# How to include a Django logging.FileHanler with Celery on ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-celery

If I do not include logging I have an Django application with Celery working fine on ElasticBeanstalk using AWS SQS.

When I include logging with a 'logging.FileHandler' celery gets **permission denied** error because it doesn't have permission rights for my log files.  This is my error

> ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'celery_file': [Errno 13]
> Permission denied: '/opt/python/log/django.log'

This is my logging setup

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler'
        },
        'file': {
            'level': log_level,
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            #'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'filename': os.environ.get('LOG_FILE_PATH', LOG_FILE_PATH + '/var/log/django.log')
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            #'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'cqc_file' :{
            'level': log_level,
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            #'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'filename': os.environ.get('LOG_FILE_PATH', LOG_FILE_PATH + '/var/log/cqc.log')
        },
        'null': {
            'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
        },
        'celery_file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.environ.get('LOG_FILE_PATH', LOG_FILE_PATH + '/var/log/celery.log'),
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'handlers': ['file'],
        },
        'debug' : { 
            'level': log_level,
            'handlers': ['file'],
        },
        'django.security.DisallowedHost': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'level' : 'CRITICAL',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['file','mail_admins'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'cqc_report' : {
            'level' : 'INFO',
            'handlers' : ['cqc_file']
        },
        'celery.task' : {
            'handlers': ['console', 'celery_file'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        }
    }
}
```

I think I need to give celery access to the django.log, celery.log and cqc.log files through and elastic beanstalk container command.  I tired this using:

```
03_change_permissions:
    command: chmod g+s /opt/python/log 
04_change_owner:
    command: chown root:wsgi /opt/python/log
05_add_celery_to_wsgi:
    command: usermod -a -G wsgi celery
```

But this just gave me an error saying no user celery (or something to that effect).

How do I get the File logging to work?

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that the user who is running the process does not have the necessary privileges it needs in order to write into the log. Your solution

```
03_change_permissions:
    command: chmod g+s /opt/python/log 
04_change_owner:
    command: chown root:wsgi /opt/python/log
05_add_celery_to_wsgi:
    command: usermod -a -G wsgi celery
```

seems to be on the right track, because when there are no privileges for a user to access a location, the solution is to provide the necessary privileges. However, your assumption that the user is `celery` seems to be wrong. A big clue for this is that this user does not exist. So, you need to make sure that

- the user to run the process exists
- you identify the correct user for the process
- the user has the necessary privileges for logging

Comment: Yes, I get all that and I tried `command: id` to find the available users.  The only user was root which makes no sense because that would mean the same user is running both so shouldn't be an issue

Comment: And if I change the command to `usermod -a -G wsgi root` I still have a permission error